# How to get the highlighted texts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the selected texts from the user(the highlighted text that user highlights).

I have the following:

```
function getSelectedTexts(){
  var t = '';
  if(window.getSelection){
    t = window.getSelection();
    console.log('1');
  }else if(document.getSelection){
    t = document.getSelection();
    console.log('2');
  }else if(document.selection){
      console.log('3');
    t = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
    return t;
   }


 $('.text_speech').live('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var textTest='';

      textTest=getSelectedTexts();
      console.log(textTest);

  })
```

My console returns

```
1

>Selection   <------object
 anchorNode: Text
 anchorOffset: 2
 baseNode: Text
 baseOffset: 2
 extentNode: Text
 extentOffset: 1
 focusNode: Text
 focusOffset: 1
 isCollapsed: false
 rangeCount: 1
 type: "Range"
 __proto__: Selection
```

I am not sure how to get the selected texts. Anyone can help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ref. Selection (MDN) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.getSelection()` returns a `Selection` object.

If you want to get the selected text without thinking more, you should do:

```js
 window.getSelection().toString()
```

But if your selection can be more complex, you should read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection).

For example the user might select text with multiple tags:

```html
 <div class="text_speech">
   <p>First paragraph</p>
   <p>Second paragraph <strong>big</strong></p>
 </div>
```

If the user select all the sentence '*paragraph Second paragraph **big***' then the easy way won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
console.log(textTest.toString());
```